# inotifywait to move a file after a user downloads it

Tags: shell-script, files, inotify

I am about to loose my mind on this and note I am not a programmer but having to tackle since our programmers are to busy. We have an sftp server where a user downloads files from us. I need to be able to move/remove that file after they have downloaded it. I am trying inotifywait and here is my bash script. I tried using incrontab but that will not work cause every time they log the file will automatically get moved or deleted before they have had a chance to grab it. Here is my bash script for inotifywait. Any suggestion or help would be greatly appreciated. This is a test script I am using on a different server with the same build kernel. Note this is in centos 7.

```
file=(/home/rhodges/prr/VZW*.prr.gz)
while true
do
inotifywait -me ACCESS /home/rhodges/prr
mv $file /home/rhodges/prr/archive >> status.txt
done
```

Comment: thanks for the response, I ended up grabbing one of programmers and making sit down with me and work on this and came up with this.           file=("/home/rhodges/prr/VZW*.prr")
dir=("/home/rhodges/prr")

regex='OPEN\s+(.*)'

inotifywait -m -q -e open $dir | while read file; do

 if [[ $file =~ $regex ]]
        then
        #echo $file
        name="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
        echo $name
mv "$dir/$name" /home/rhodges/prr/archive/
 fi
done